# I would like to align/centre a image within a cell in excel

Tags: excel, image, alignment

I would like to align/centre a image within a cell in excel.

When I insert the image into a cell it goes to the top left of the cell. I can manually drag the image to the centre however this is very time consuming as I have multiple cells of various sizes. Dragging the cell by the bottom corner is not an option.(see image 2)

[image: Image default position after insertion]

[image]

Comment: Each yellow oval is a image. I would like to centre all the images without manually dragging them to the centre of the cell.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to achive this, provided that the image is stored in a file:

1. Insert the image from an existing file
2. Snap the borders of the image to the borders of the cell by holding down the ALT-key and dragging the image borders using the mouse (forget about the aspect ratio for just a second)
3. Right-click the image, select "Change Picture..." and re-select the image file

Every time you change the size of the cell, use "Change Picture" again to *repair* the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Simply join the cells together and put the image inside them.

To do this, select the cells that you want and put Arrange All, then the cells will be together and you can put the image inside them.

Comment: Do you understand my question. Each yellow oval is a image. I would like to centre the oval image in cells of various sizes.